# PHP Parse txt Files to get specific Data

Tags: php, parsing

i want to get some information from a txt file... have read already through some questions, but there was no solution for my one

```
inventoryItemData {
  header {
    id: 3758164995
  }
  itemType: 1
  itemID: 2561
  count: 1
  isOwnerList: false
  fromLand: 0
  sourceLen: 0
}
```

This is in my text file and i want to get the item type and the itemID
as a String so in this example like

```
'(2561,1)'
```

i know that i can work with a foreach and save every single String into an array but i don't know how i can get the two numbers

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: What generated that txt file in the first place?

Comment: it was a python script and yes i also think JSON

Comment: @NoLand That data isn't valid JSON. Whatever the format is, that isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $file = fopen('input.txt', "r");
    $itemID = '';
    $itemType = '';
    while($line = fgets($file))
    {
            if(preg_match('/itemType: (\d+)/', $line, $matches))
            {
                    $itemType = $matches[1];
            }
            else if(preg_match('/itemID: (\d+)/', $line, $matches))
            {
                    $itemID = $matches[1];
            }
    }
    $string = "($itemID,$itemType)";
    print $string . "\n";
```

**edit**
and the version capable of supporting multiple entries in a file

```
$file = fopen('input.txt', "r");
$itemID = null;
$itemType = null;
$arrayAssoc = array();
$arrayStrings = array();
while($line = fgets($file))
{
        if(preg_match('/itemType: (\d+)/', $line, $matches))
        {
                $itemType = $matches[1];
        }
        else if(preg_match('/itemID: (\d+)/', $line, $matches))
        {
                $itemID = $matches[1];
        }
        if($itemType != null && $itemID != null)
        {
                $arrayAssoc[$itemID] = $itemType;
                $arrayString[] = "($itemID,$itemType)";
                $itemType = $itemID = null;
        }
}
print_r($arrayAssoc);
print_r($arrayString);
```

Comment: i don't think that this will work like i want... i am having a txt file with a lot of these InventoryData Containers in it, and i want to have the itemID and itemType of every Container in an array... so the itemtype and id belonging to each other of each container

Comment: well its easy to tweak the above to do that. do you want it an associative array? or an array full of (1234, 1) ?

Comment: an array full of these strings... so for example array[0] = (1234,1) array[2] = (1235,3)

Comment: @pala_ So if OP would search for 3 things he would have to add 1 variable and 1 if statement? not very flexible ?!

Comment: and if he wanted to build his string array from yours, and the order of itemid/itemtype flipped in a few entries in the file? This is a tool for the job, not lets write a parser for a weird file format.

Comment: @pala_ 1. Why don't you write this under my answer if it is for it?  2. *and if he wanted to build his string array from yours* np 1x echo with implode and done 3. *and the order of itemid/itemtype flipped in a few entries in the file?*  Makes no differences still works 4. You didn't answered my question in the comments

Comment: 1) because it was a response. if i wrote it under your answer it'd seem douchey since this one was already accepted. here it had context. 2) you might want to check his required result before making that claim. 3) you might want to test that before making that claim. don't bother responding. i wont again.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(First I get all lines into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then I grab all lines with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) which are(contain) one element of the `$search` array. At the end I just filter the text from the searching with [`preg_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) out)

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $search = ["itemType:", "itemID:"];
    $arr = preg_filter("/(\b" . implode("|\b", $search) . ")/", "", preg_grep("/(\b" . implode("|\b", $search) . ")/", $lines));

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [4] => 1 [5] => 2561 )
```

Comment: Wait.  Why search with two waves of regex?  Is this still your advice in 2022?